# Python Flask Restful After Request Delete File

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I am writing a simple PDF converter inside container. Send docx and get PDF, but I don't want file to stay on server, therefor I wish to delete them after download request.

I tried to use flask after_this_request on get request on Download(Resource)

```py
class Downloader(Resource):
    def get(self, doc_id):

        folder, file_name = FileConverter.download_file(doc_id)
        if not folder:
            return jsonify({"status": "NOTOK", "error": "No File"})

        @after_this_request
        def _clean_file():
            FileConverter.delete_file(doc_id)
        return send_from_directory(folder, file_name, as_attachment=True)
```

FileConverter.delete_file checks if file exists and uses os.remove to delete it, however this part of code corrupt PDF into unreadable. If I remove @after_this_request, I get working PDF.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it like this:

```
class Downloader(Resource):
def get(self, doc_id):

    folder, file_name = FileConverter.download_file(doc_id)
    if not folder:
        return jsonify({"status": "NOTOK", "error": "No File"})

    try:
        return send_from_directory(folder, file_name, as_attachment=True)
    finally:
        FileConverter.delete_file(doc_id)
```